# UIWebView doesn't resize webpage in splitview detailController

Tags: ios, xcode, ipad, uiwebview, uisplitview

I'm developing a universal iOS app for iPhone and iPad. I'm having some trouble with the splitview in the iPad app. In the detailController there's a UIWebView where I load a webpage that should autoresize(that's in the css from the webpage). In portrait it's ok, but in landscape mode, the webpage doesn't resize at all. I also checked the "Scales Page To Fit" button. But this doesn't work either! Is there a way to resize the webpage in safari manually?
Here are some screenshots:
iPad Portrait:
[image: iPad Portrait]

[image: iPad Landscape]

Landscape

Comment: Check the frame of your self.view and web view on rotation. I think your webview is keeping its frame. Probably just need to set the resizing options in IB.

Comment: Also @Jojas is right. If you're going to ask questions its nice to accept the answers.